# subprocess will not output file when ran from Spyder IDE

Tags: subprocess, spyder, python-3.9, anaconda3

I am trying to write a short script to call ilastik (an interactive machine learning software for image segmentation) as part of my pipeline. My script can find my files in the input folder but will not generate an output. However, if I copy the command I asked it to print and paste it into a command prompt, I get an output. I have many files and do not want to have to copy and paste a command for every single one. How can I get it to run straight from the IDE?

```
from pathlib import Path
import subprocess


in_folder = Path("C:\\Users\\Diego Caron\\Headless_Test_In")
out_folder = Path("C:\\Users\\Diego Caron\\Headless_Test_Out")

for in_file in in_folder.glob("*.tif"):
    out_file = out_folder / in_file.name.replace(".tif", "_Simple Segmentation.np")
    print(f"Processing {in_file} -> {out_file}")
    command = [

            "C:\\Users\\Diego Caron\\ilastik-1.4.0\\ilastik.exe",

            '--headless',

            '--project="C:\\Users\\Diego Caron\\NLGF_Segmentation.ilp"',

            '--output_format="numpy"',

            '--export_source="Simple Segmentation"',

            f'--raw_data="{in_file}"',

            f'--output_filename_format="{out_file}"'
]

    print("COMMAND=", "  ".join(command))

    process = subprocess.run(command, check = True)
```

Comment: What happens if you add double quotes to the first line in your command (i.e. add single quotes so that the double quotes wrap `C:`  etc. `'"C:\\Users\\Diego Caron\\ilastik-1.4.0\\ilastik.exe"'` In particular spaces tend to cause problems with commands and your path has a space `Diego Caron` so I generally try to wrap those with quotes.